# Merge links with text without changing text

Tags: excel, merge, hyperlink

I have Web links in one column and plain text in another.

I would like to merge the links from A to B without B changing name.

(Basically want to move in the links without changing the name of the original cells.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the merge in a third column (for example the C column), you can do this fairly simple with the HYPERLINK function. Try to use the following in cell C1:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1, B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set a formula for the cells with names on them.

1) Copy the entire column of names to a different column.

2) Add this formula to the first few names of the new column.
=HYPERLINK(*linklocation*,*namelocation*)

3) Select the entire column of the copied names.

4) Use the "Fill" tool and fill down. Done.

Example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/4798c6bb09826b6a2b94167c512b08b6.png))</sub>